# Google K8S - Stackdriver engine monitoring is enabled byt cant see logs in Google Logs Viewer

Tags: logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

PROBLEM: I get monitoring information in stackdriver dashboards but I cant see logs in google Logs Viewer (also nothing with gcloud logging read "resource.type=k8s_container" to this cluster)

Google K8S - Master version 1.13.6-gke.6

On my K8S cluster is Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring Enabled, Legacy Stackdriver Logging Disabled, Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring Disabled.

If I switch to Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring and Legacy Stackdriver Logging, it works (with resource.type=container).

Cluster use service with permission (Role editor (owner not help))

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
Permissions for cluster

Stackdriver Logging API - Write Only
Stackdriver Monitoring API - Full
On every node runing fluentd-gcp-*

I want to have Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring Enabled and also see logs from all (pods) containers from this cluster in Google Logs Viewer